# Stop running project automatically

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I've found very annoying to see the "Simulator in use" error which happens when few projects are opened and on one I've build and ran it and forgot to stop it, then I tried to run another project but only "Simulator in use" error appears.

I have to go through all projects currently opened and see which has running process and stop it manually.

Is it possible to stop any running projects when CMD+R is clicked?

Comment: My educated guess says that this is not possible at the moment. The answer by Adrian is not ideal because it'll just the same as quitting the simulator and then running it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of ensuring that the simulator isn't running, is to run from terminal (to test) the following:

```
killall "iPhone Simulator"
```

What that does is kill the process called "iPhone Simulator", this is pretty much the same for any unix based platform.

The only other best way I could suggest is to have a bash script kill the simulator manually before compilation i.e. add a "run script" target to the build phase (At the beginning) to execute something to the order of:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall "iPhone Simulator"
exit 0
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo killall "iPhone Simulator"
exit 0
```

depending on your user group etc...

Usually the Simulator isn't terminated when your app crashes whilst it's running or you prematurely stop execution from a breakpoint.

Too add and test the above:

1. Open any project which you want to have kill a running simulator in the background.
2. In the navigator, click on the Project Root 
   [image: Navigator with Project Root Highlighted]
3. In the editor area, select to highlight the project target (i.e. the project you're going to build and run on the simulator). In the image below, it's devTesting under TARGETS.
   [image]
4. Click on "Build Phases" in the editor area.
5. Click on the "Editor Menu" at the top of the screen.
6. Click on "Add Build Phase > Add Run Script Build Phase" (you'll then see a "Run Script") section appear just to the right of the edit window.. Usually at the end of the list.
7. Drag that up to as high as you can in the list. Usually, the most it can go is directly below "target dependencies"... So 2nd in the list.
8. Expand the Run Script section.
9. Paste in either of the script examples I listed, the former should work fine, you should have something which appears as follows:
   [image]

And there you have it. If it doesn't work for any reason, you can always check the build log to see what the output is.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive, I'm noob to the apple world, would you be able to write kind of step-by-step description on how to set it?

Comment: Just to add, the project structure is different on mine as it's a Mac App, but the steps are still the same.

Comment: Just added exit 0 to the end of the script.... This is important as the build will fail if the sim isn't running.

Comment: Thank you this is very good answer, I'll wait a bit maybe there is a script option to actualy go through all XCode opened projects and execute "stop running" shortcut "CMD + .".